# Python : index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem, in my code is simply

```
for i in xrange(len(acid1)):
        j=0
        k=0
        while (j<worksheet.ncols):
            if (acid1[i].lower()==worksheet.row_values(0)[j+1].lower()):
                col1=j+1
                while (k<worksheet.nrows):
                    if (acid2[i].lower()==worksheet.row_values(k+1)[0].lower()):
                        row1=k+1
                        break
                    else:
                        k+=1
                break
            else:
                j+=1
```

and in line

```
if (aminokwas1[i].lower()==worksheet.row_values(0)[j+1].lower()):
```

I get an IndexError: list index out of range. Does anybody know the reason? I don't use any list or anything that I could get out of range. Please help.

Comment: `aminokwas1` and `worksheet.row_values(0)` look like lists to me.

Comment: I don't see the line in your code,

Answer (score 0):

When `j == worksheet.ncols-1`, it appears that `j+1` is not a valid index for `worksheet.row_values(0)`. Presumably, you make that check for `j` because the indices for `worksheet.row_values` are 0 through `worksheet.cols - 1`.

Comment: It doesn't work for j insted of j+1. I have found that "k=0" should be in the beginning of "j" loop, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: You have a similar problem with `k`, as well as the fact that you are using both `ncols` and `nrows` as an upper limit for the index into `row_values(0)`. One of them is probably the wrong one to use.